# What is the best way for non-developers to create XAML Grids?

Tags: wpf, xaml, forms, blend

We need to have **non-developers** create dozens of input forms with XAML.

The best solution I found was the free **XAML Power Toys** since you can create and edit grids visually, also create from classes.

I took a look at **Blend 3** quickly, dragged a Grid into my Window but found **no options** to actually create, say, a 4 x 10 grid with labels. I thought Blend would have these kinds of options so that designers could **quickly design** a grid with label/control pairs.

**Am I missing something about Blend, or does it really not have any input form designing features?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. Would that be any more natural than, say, an option to create a StackPanel with images or a DockPanel with TextBoxes?

What I'm getting at is that even though a grid with labels is a natural UI design for you, most designers (whom Blend is targeting) would regard such features as "Microsoft Word-ish" or even (shudder) "Front Page-ish" and stifling their creativity. I guess.

Actually, both Blend and Visual Studio allow you to create and edit grids visually. It's really quite fast once you get the hang of it.

And then there is copy/paste, of course..

Comment: So after I drag a grid on a page in Blend, I would like to tell it to have 4 columns and 32 rows and then I would like to change the margins on all of the cells. Is that possible? This seems to me to be basic functionality that designers need to work with grids, otherwise they are in XAML typing in dozens of RowDefinition lines, etc.

Comment: +1 for the copy-and-paste pattern, which is what we ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Blend does have this capability.  You can even do this directly in Visual Studio's WPF Designer.  It's a matter of learning the tools.  You can still just make a grid, set it to 4 columns and 10 rows (which adds the Column and Row definitions to the grid), and then drag in the elements you want.

The problem is probably more that you're trying to treat WPF the same way as a tool like Windows Forms - in which case, it does a horrible job.  WPF is all about learning how to use WPF effectively, which is a very different mindset (in my experience, it's usually easier for non-developers to pick up, but tough for developers).

There are not automatic grid creation with label/entry control tools, however.  This is more likely a job for something like the DataGrid from the [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf).